# Is there a way to resolve this `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')` error?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch an action to the redux store, but continue to get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at reducer (redux-toolkit.esm.js?8ccc:595:1)
    at reducer (redux-toolkit.esm.js?8ccc:705:1)
    at eval (BrandMetrics.js?6984:65:27)
```

The data that I was trying to send to the store is an array that was fetched from an API inside of `useEffect` (I don't know if this is the reason for the error), but I was able to fetch the data successfully. Can you help resolve this issue?
Any and all pointers will be very much appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function Metrics() {
  const [store, setStore] = useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const baseUrl = "/api/stores";
    fetch(baseUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
         //data was fetched successfully as expected
        dispatch(allRetail(data)); //Error dispatching this action to store
        return data;
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

My retailSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  stores: [],
};

const allRetailSlice = createSlice({
  name: "retailList",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    allRetail: (state, action) => {
      state.stores = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { allRetail } = allRetailSlice.actions;
export default allRetailSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: The code you shared looks correct to me. It looks like the error is coming from another part of your code, like somewhere you try to access `type.something` and type is undefined.

Comment: @BaptisteF. Thanks for your response. I guess I have some digging to do. Thanks again for your input